# Get Safari's current location from command-line?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, safari

How can I get the location of the current tab of the frontmost window of Safari in a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

I created the following shell script at `~/bin/currenturl`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to return URL of front document' | tr -d '\n'
```

(and `chmod +x`'d it of course.)